# Using audio recorder at android simulator

Tags: android, audio, android-studio, android-emulator, audio-recording

I want to use an audio capture feature at my app. I followed [this link at developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html#example). 
I'm using *Android Studio 1.4* and a *Nexus 5 with Api21* as virtual device. At developer.android it is descripted that it's not possible to use the audio capture feature with an simulator:

> Note: The Android Emulator does not have the ability to capture audio, but actual devices are likely to provide these capabilities.

But is this an information that is up to date? I'm able to use the record button but the activity crashes after pressing stop. I can see the *audiorecordtest.3gp* file on the simulated device and if I save it to my computer I can play my recorded audio. The crash comes without any shown exception. If I ask for

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE);
```

I got back a true. It seems like the simulator is able to capture audio but can't handle correctly the stopping of it? Is there a way to get around?

Answer (score 0):

One aspect of Tamper Checking involves testing for an Emulator running your app...

In [THIS](https://www.airpair.com/android/posts/adding-tampering-detection-to-your-android-app) article (Paragraph 4.1), Emulator detection is described... The tests detect many emulators, but throw some "false positives", depending on the device.

False positives render some emulator test's, described in the article, not appropriate for production, but are fine in a test environment where you know your devices and their test responses.